# How can I get my data from sendgrid?

Tags: email, sendmail, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid api to send various email(s) my user(s). At sendgrid portal they have give us statistics in a limited way. I can't search my queries as i want. thats why I want that data in my own database. so, I can query as per my need.

My question is, Is there any way to get data/statistics my of account? any service of sendgrid which is provide my data?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you enable our event webhook, your application can consume all the data/statistics itself and store that in your db. So for example, SendGrid will post info on the following types of events back to your site (Processed, Dropped, Delivered, Deferred, Bounced, Opened, Link Clicked, Marked as Spam, or Unsubscribed)

You can get more info on our event webhook here:
[Event Webhook Docs](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html)

Those docs show examples on the data we post to your site as well as the parameters we send for each type of event.

Comment: I am using node.js to build my web app. and within this app I am sending bulk emails to my users. for that I am using sendgrid-mustache (https://github.com/jiem/sendgrid-mustache). So how can I get email status?

Comment: @ManishSapkal That's probably another question, but you'd set up an endpoint that accepts post data and stores it in a database, (ideally, with the various parameters saved individually (in fields (SQL) or object values (noSQL)) for lookup later). [Here's an example of how to setup the endpoint, using Express](http://d.pr/n/Lm26)